# Notifications Footer in-App slider Google Plus and Facebook - How to?

Tags: android

I would like to know how to implement a sliding in-App Notifications Footer as it is in Google+ and Facebook android App.

Mainly any clue how to achieve that sliding effect would be awesome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those applications are using what's called a Sliding Drawer widget. You can look at the [documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) for how to use it.

Comment: +1 for pointing me in a direction what seems like the right one. Thanks.

Comment: I will accept it after I am done implementing it successfully accotding to the article.